# Apply isoformat to range of python dates

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp

I'm working on amping up the Python skills (I work heavy in R) and I'm trying to replicate the creation of a list of dates in python in iso format for passing as strings into a sql server connection:

here is the list:

```
#step 1:create date list
base = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 31)
date_list = [base - datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, 90)]
**strong text**
```

now how do I turn it into an iso like this:

```
base.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

but retain the list element, so change the entire list in date_list into iso formats?

Comment: Clarifying question: you want to convert the current items in `date_list` to iso format of `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Is that right?

Comment: yes correct, if there is a better way of approaching this than the code provided above I am open to suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I have actually found the answer for anyone interested:

```
#apply a different function across lists
date_strings = [dt.strftime('"%Y-%m-%d"') for dt in date_list]
```

comes from:
[Python: create human-friendly string from a list of datetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10609081/python-create-human-friendly-string-from-a-list-of-datetimes)